# What is known about the homotopy type of the classifier of subobjects of simplicial sets?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, topos-theory

For the presheaf topos $\mathrm{PSh}(C)$, the subobject classifier is the presheaf $\Omega$ such that

- For $c \in C$, $\Omega(c)$ is the set of all subobjects of the functor $\mathrm{Hom}(-, c)$
- For $f: c \to c'$, $\Omega(f)(F) = \{g: a \to c | gf \in F\}$, where a subfunctor $F < \mathrm{Hom}(-, c')$, and the definite subfunctor $\mathrm{Hom}(-, c)$ we have written as a set of morphisms with arbitrary $\mathrm{dom}$ and fixed $\mathrm{cod}$.

So in $\mathrm{sSet}$ we have:

- 2 points $0$ and $1$ corresponding to the empty and full subsets of $\Delta^0$
- 5 segments corresponding to subsets of $\Delta^1$ ($\Delta^1, \partial \Delta^1, \{0\}, \{1\}, \varnothing$) which are glued respectively as

1. degenerate simplex $s(1)$
2. a loop on $1$ (let us conditionally write: $[11]$)
3. 1-simplex $[10]$
4. 1-simplex $[01]$
5. degenerate simplex $s(0)$

- 19 triangles corresponding to subsets of $\Delta^2$ ..

The sequence of numbers of simplices is called [dedekind numbers](https://oeis.org/A014466).

What is known about the homotopy type of this space? Maybe it is contractible? Or is it homotopically equivalent to a well-known space? If not, maybe we can say something about its homotopy groups, cohomology rings, etc?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It’s not hard to check that the subobject classifier $\Omega$ is trivially fibrant, and so its homotopy type is trivial. Orthogonality of $\Omega \to 1$ against a map $i : A \to B$ corresponds to the property that any subobject $A' \to A$ extends to a subobject $B' \to B$ such that $i^*B' = A'$; when $i$ is mono, this is always possible, with canonical solutions given by the direct image $\exists_i A'$ and the dual image $\forall_i A'$.

Nothing here is special to simplicial sets: this argument anpplies equally in any model structure on a topos in which all cofibrations are monomorphisms.

This argument appears (tersely!) in the proof of Theorem  1.4.3 of Cisinski 2006, [*Les préfaisceaux comme modèles des types d’homotopie (Presheaves as models for homotopy types)*, 2006](http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_2006__308__R1_0/) (thanks to Tim Campion in comments for the precise reference).  A couple of closely related arguments — firstly the fibrancy of a universe classifying certain fibrations, corresponding to showing that those fibrations extend along trivial cofibrations, and secondly the univalence of this universe — appear in my 2012 paper with Chris Kapulkin, [*The simplicial model of univalent foundations (after Voevodsky)*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2851), in Sections 2.1, 2.2, and 3.2.

Comment: Presumably you mean trivially _fibrant_.

Comment: Wow, indeed, thanks!

Comment: @ZhenLin: D’oh, of course — thanks!

Comment: It appears in the proof of Thm 1.4.3. Note that Cisinski calls the subobject classifier "the Lawvere object". See also 1.3.9

Comment: @TimCampion: Fantastic, thanks — edited into the answer.